# What is wrong with my docker commands? Cant connect mongo express to mongo db

Tags: mongodb, docker

I've had the MongoDB container runnning without incident for quite some time.  When I try to start Mongo Express.  I get an error telling me it cant connect to the database.  What is wrong with the commands I'm using?

```bash
docker run -d \
  -p 27017:27017 \
  -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin \
  -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password \
  --name mongodb \
  --network mongo-network \
  mongo

docker run -d \
  -p 8081:8081 \
  -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=ee163c15dcf2 \
  -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin \
  -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password \
  --network mongo_network \
  --name mongo-express \
  mongo-express
```

I got the host name of the MongoDB server by running

```bash
docker exec <container_name_or_id> hostname
```

Here are the logs of the Mongo Express container that keeps exiting.

```
root@ubuntu-s-2vcpu-2gb-nyc1-01:~# docker logs 7519be7544de
Welcome to mongo-express
------------------------


(node:8) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: Current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
Could not connect to database using connectionString: mongodb://admin:password@ee163c15dcf2:27017/"
(node:8) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [ee163c15dcf2:27017] on first connect [Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN ee163c15dcf2
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:66:26) {
  name: 'MongoNetworkError'
}]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:441:11)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:564:14
    at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:1000:11
    at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:32:7
    at callback (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:300:5)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:330:7)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:26)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
(node:8) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:8) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
root@ubuntu-s-2vcpu-2gb-nyc1-01:~# docker exec ee163c15dcf2 hostname
ee163c15dcf2
root@ubuntu-s-2vcpu-2gb-nyc1-01:~#
```

I tried to start the Mongo Express container but it would not connect.

Comment: You should be able to use the `docker run --name` of the container, `mongodb`, as a host name when the two containers are on the same network; you do not need to `docker inspect` anything.  `hostname` returns a container-private name that can't be used outside its own container.

Answer (score 0):

> there is a grammatical error in what you have posted above

##### 1.

the network is **mongo-network**, instead of **mongo_network**,

##### 2.

the value of **ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER** should be the **CONTAINER ID** of the container mongodb,

And on my ubuntu, it's worked fine.

- Use this url on the brower: SERVER_IP:8081, you would see the effect.

---

As @[David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze) said, In order to avoid changes of container ID of **mongodb** during rebuild operations, it is recommended to use the container name here that is mongodb,

```bash
docker run -d \
  -p 8081:8081 \
  -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb \
  -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin \
  -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password \
  --network mongo_network \
  --name mongo-express \
  mongo-express
```